# What is the minimal order of a finite nonabelian group that cannot be written as semidirect product of two of its proper subgroups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

I have proved also that if a group is simple, then it satisfies the property.
So, $A_5$, which has order 60, satisfies the property. And finally, I have proved that nonabelian groups of order less than 60 cannot be simple.
But I still cant conclude that the minimal order is 60.
Any hints?

Comment: I assume you want to reword your question to read "What is the minimal order of a finite *non-abelian* group that cannot be written as semidirect product of two of its *proper* subgroups?"

Comment: Yes, you are wright!

Comment: Eight...${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$